# do we have to create a different account for publishing android app and chrome extension or we can both with one account paying $5 for once?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Do we have to create a different accounts for publishing android app and chrome extension separately,
Or we can use same account to publish the android app and also publish the chrome extension, by paying $5 for once?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google's policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: You can use one account, but you have to pay 5$ for the extension and 25$ for the android app. Source: own experience.